# Do any bosses outside their zone, drop their drops?

Tags: sakuna-of-rice-and-ruin

Do *any* bosses outside their zone, drop their drops?

For example, the non-Forest-of-Supplication White Gale, does it drop Pheasant Feathers? Or am I just really unlucky, killing it ~20 or more times, with the Material Drop Boost hat, and not even seeing one Feather?

I'm talking about the bosses in:

> Amagaeshi shrine

Although... I am restricted to...

> the one on the 35rd floor...

Other enemies and their drops would be the Black Shadow, and its Black Deer Leather, the Purple Scourge and its Boar Tusk... The Crimson Current... I don't think have any special drops?

I just want to know if any of the bosses have the drops, so I can at least grind White Gale with some knowledge.

Comment: Hope my answer helps, I'm super interested in this game now, so might pick it up.

Comment: @Regnegade - Hope you have as much fun as I do! Possibly more because I'm deliberately challenging myself and being inefficient. Hehe!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing from the asker, it appears that the wiki may be wrong. However, this is still the most thorough answer so it will remain until more testing can be done.

Based on my research, I'd say that yes, it is possible to get these drops *in* the area you mentioned by killing the bosses, listed [here](https://sakuna-of-rice-and-ruin.fandom.com/wiki/Pheasant_Feather) on the Fandom page for the Pheasant Feather, [here](https://sakuna-of-rice-and-ruin.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Deer_Leather) for the Black Deer Leather, and [here](https://sakuna-of-rice-and-ruin.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Deer_Leather) for the Boar Tusk.

This answer is specifically referring to

> Amagaeshi Shrine

I found a post on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/sakunaofriceandruin/comments/kaati2/is_there_a_comprehensive_list_of_drops_for_the/) linking to a [Japanese Wiki](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://hyperwiki.jp/sakuna/amagaeshi/) for the game detailing the drops for the area. I'd include the all drops here, but the tables are too massive so I'll just include the few I believe to be relevant. It states that

> levels 55 and 60

have a rare drop of a Boar Fang (which I believe to be a Google Translate issue), or Boar Tusk. It also mentions a Hakuchi Feather which I believe is a mistranslation for Pheasant Feather for these floors as well.

I also found the [Fandom](https://sakuna-of-rice-and-ruin.fandom.com/wiki/Amagaeshi_Shrine/Floors_41_to_45) page for the area, and it lists Pheasant Feathers as possible loot, as well as Boar Tusks. There is also [a post](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/265779-sakuna-of-rice-and-ruin/79130014/947505809) on Gamefaqs mentioning one of your concerned items in the area as well:

> floor 11-15 for boar tusk chance

Comment: Interesting... So, if I were strong enough to take on those places, I'd get them guaranteed... But no info on whether the monsters / demons drop them by themselves...

Comment: If you take a look [here](https://sakuna-of-rice-and-ruin.fandom.com/wiki/Pheasant_Feather) on the Fandom, it does actually say that you can get the Feathers from killing the White Gale in that location.

Comment: @Malady I've edited my answer to clarify information that you pointed out was unsupported, and added my sources for my beliefs.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Gonna spend some time grinding White Gale to see if the Wiki info is true!

Comment: If it is, then I'm not seeing it, at the location I'm doing it at... Adding a note that the wiki might be wrong, would make me happy that the only answer, and auto-bountied, is as accurate as it can be?

Comment: I'll add it to the end of the answer. I'll also see if someone can dredge through the decompiled code and figure it out. Hopefully I'll have time to buy and test it myself in the coming weeks. @Malady

Comment: @Regneade - If you do end up buying, tell me, and I'll rebounty at 100, to toss some your way?

Comment: I'll accept this because if no one else makes a better answer, you should get the 50 rep.